# if-else in a python list comprehension using dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am trying to replace a word from the contractions dict. However, I want to return the word when it doesnt exists in contraction dict but  it does in the list.

Currently my implementation fails if the word in the list doesnt exist in the dictionary.

```
contractions = {
"costumer": "customer",
"billl": "bill",
"acct": "account"}
abc = ['acct','costumer','abc']

[w.replace(w,contractions[w]) for w in abc if w in contractions else w for w in abc]
```

expected output: `['account','customer','abc']`

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a description

Comment: `print([contractions[i] if i in contractions else i for i in abc])` ?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Sayse, just corrected

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, just added

Comment: Great, added an answer, please check @Shoaibkhanz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use value from the key if the word exists in the dictionary, else use the word itself using `dict.get(key,default_value)`

`contractions.get(word,word)` gets the value for key `word` from `contractions` if the key is present, else it uses the word` itself

```
contractions = {
"costumer": "customer",
"billl": "bill",
"acct": "account"}
abc = ['acct','costumer','abc']

res = [contractions.get(word,word)  for word in abc]
print(res)
#['account', 'customer', 'abc']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
contractions = {
"costumer": "customer",
"billl": "bill",
"acct": "account"}
abc = ['acct','costumer','abc']

[w.replace(w,contractions[w]) if w in contractions else w for w in abc ]
```

Gives you:

```
['account', 'customer', 'abc']
```

Comment: You are running a list comprehension without using it's values anywhere, that is bad practice

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with if when you please the if in the right position

```
contractions = {
"costumer": "customer",
"billl": "bill",
"acct": "account"}
abc = ['acct','costumer','abc']

res=[contractions[w] if w in contractions else w for w in abc]

print(res)
```

but dict has also an handy method for that

```
res=[contractions.get(w,w) for w in abc]

print(res)
```